# A GridView with headers in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a grid view for a Windows Universal app.

Ideally, I'd like to have a grid-type view that can scroll both horizontally and vertically, but to have the first row and the first column permanently visible when scrolling, wherever the user moves in the data (example: freezing panes in Excel).

I'm unsure whether or not I should continue to use a Grid, switch to a GridView, or use multiple ListViews to emulate a grid.  The Universal Windows samples seem to have what I'm looking for in terms of a header that doesn't disappear when scrolling (a simple group) for both Grid/ListView, but what they don't seem to have is the ability to have all the views scroll when one is.

Any ideas?  I've tried using the SplitPane control as well for the first column (that column being a ListView), but I still suffer from the same problem of simultaneous scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

XAML:

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="400" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Grid Background="Green" Width="1000">
            <Line X1="0" X2="1000" Y1="0" Y2="100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="left" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Grid Background="Red" Height="1000">
            <Line X1="0" X2="100" Y1="0" Y2="1000" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="middle" ViewChanged="middle_ViewChanged" Background="Blue" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid Background="Blue" Height="1000" Width="1000">
            <Line X1="0" X2="1000" Y1="0" Y2="1000" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void middle_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        top.ChangeView(middle.HorizontalOffset, null, null, true);
        left.ChangeView(null, middle.VerticalOffset, null, true);
    }
```

You can put whatever you want in those ScrollViewers, the lines are there just to make it obvious what scrolls in lockstep with what.